# Internal DNS names not resolving

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I was actually doing some quick labs exercise when I noticed this issue where is ping to an internal IP works but if I ping with machine name it does not work. Here is what I did:

a.) Create a GCP project. Leave all the default firewall rules in place

b.) Create a VM in us-central-1 (any region) call it - mynet-us-vm

c.) Create a VM in eu-west-1 (any region) - call it - mynet-eu-vm

d.) SSH to mynet-us-vm from the console

e.) Run this commands : ping -c 3 <Enter mynet-eu-vm's internal IP here>- It works

f.) Run this command: ping -c 3 mynet-eu-vm  - Does not work! Getting below error

Getting Error:

> "ping: mynet-eu-vm: Name or service not known"

Answer (score 0):

For Internal DNS resolution to work there are multiple factors that affect this:

On the client Instance running ping the resolv.conf file must have the metadata server (169.254.169.254) as it’s nameserver and the search domains must be set similarly to the example on [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf), if using a Google provided image this configuration should already be set correctly.

Additionally, verify the hostname registered for the Instance “mynet-eu-vm” this can be done by running curl against the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#view_instance_dns_name), the output to this will be the full FQDN which will confirm whether the resolv.conf file should be set to [Zonal DNS or Global DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf) and if the hostname for the Instance is the same as the one being used with ping.

If running “dig FQDN @169.254.169.254” works but ping still fails this would mean that the Instance is trying to resolve against a different nameserver, or that the search list on resolv.conf is incorrect.

If the above steps fail I suggest raising a support case with [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) or opening a [new Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) since following the steps provided does not result in the same behavior and likely it’s something specific to your setup.